# data structure to search for a word in a phrase

Tags: java, android, data-structures, collections, full-text-search

(I'm developing with android sdk, but maybe it's not important)
I read from a file several phrase and save them in a collection.

eg.:
"hello world",
"you say hello",
"big world"

I want to make something like the google homepage. I've an edit text, where the user can write one or more words. When he type the first word, (eg: "hello"), I want to show in some text fields, the  possible candidate phrase (eg: "hello world", "mark say hello").
Now the user could type another word to refine the search and so on.

There's already something that do this?
Which is the best data structure to old this data?
I was thinking about an MultiMap with word and idPhrase (eg: ("hello",0), ("world",0), ("you",1), ...)
I was thinking to get a sub-set (eg. if the user type "hello", i would remove the third phrase) and so on, to refine the search.
(But maybe is better to save the phrase from file to a sqlLite DB instead of a collection, I don't know...)

Exist better way to do this?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html

Answer (score 0):

Inverted index is the right data structure for this. Not sure if there is an implementation of it somewhere on the net (for sure there is) but it is easy to build it yourself. Take a look here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index

Algorithm should be something like this:

```
for(String phrase : phrases)  
{     
    for(String word : phrase.split(" "))  
    {  
        List temp= map.get(word); 
        if (temp == null) {
            temp= new ArrayList<String>();
            map.put(word, temp);
        }
        temp.add(phrase);
    }  
}
```

Later on, you just query the map for the user query (a word) and print the list of phrases.

If you need a phrase search, you might want to look at the: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf–idf Otherwise, find a union of the lists returned for the each word in the phrase query.

Comment: But this solution work only if the user insert one single word, what if do he insert two or more word?

Answer (score 0):

Then you're looking for a TextWatcher.

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Here implemens the logic stuff that at each new character entered

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Here's a [little example with a listView](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-edittext-filter.html).

Another approach could also be to use a [custom suggestion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html).